# How can I make this multiply method return a polynomial that doesn't have repeated exponents?

Tags: java, arraylist, multiplication, polynomials, polynomial-math

I need this method to return the simplified polynomial
for example: if the result is 3.00x^4 + 6.00x^2 + 2.00x^3 + 4.00x+x^2 + 2.00 i need it to return it simplified to 3.00x^4 + 2.00x^3 + 7.00x^2 + 4.00x + 2.00

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use an integer array. The coefficient of x<sup>n</sup> goes in the n<sup>th</sup> place of the array. And as you add it to the list, you'll add the number to whatever is there. Integer arrays have 0 in every position by default.

This would add polynomials for you.